# Subscriptions swift

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I've added subscriptions with App Store Connect and when I run it through Xcode I can see my subscription plans and purchase it. But when I send it my application to Test Flight I can't see my subscription plans. What is the problem?